# Get most recent file of a given type in a directory with C++ <filesystem> library

Tags: c++, filesystems

I am trying to find the most recent `.mkv` file in a directory with the C++ `<filesystem>` library, but I can't figure out a working solution. What is a working way to do so?

Comment: Using `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` in a loop, you can use each `std::filesystem::directory_entry` given to you to check its `path().extension()` and `last_write_time()` methods.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the directory (`directory_iterator`), checking the extension (`path::extension`) and the write time (`last_write_time`)? If so what problems did you encounter?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Wow, I was just fixing my spelling when your comment popped up.